# Can I access android widget reference from different thread other than UI thread..?

Tags: android

In Android, I thought I cannot access ui objects from a different thread other than the UI thread. That is why handlers and all there to communicate details back to ui thread.

I tried simple example below. I tried to update progress bar from a new thread created. It worked. I thought I would get exception. Can you please explain why I did not get exception.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Main3Activity";

    Thread thread;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        thread = new Thread(new MyThread());

        progressBar  = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        Log.i(TAG, "run: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

        thread.start();

    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "run: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                progressBar.setProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProgressBar internally checks before updating progress whether it is in UI thread or not.

If progress is updated from non ui-thread then it will make its own runnable which runs on UI-Thread.

```
if (mUiThreadId == Thread.currentThread().getId()) {
// update progress bar
} else {
// create ui thread before updating progress bar
}
```

please see [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setProgress%28int%29) for code details.

Comment: nice question lot of people have doubts on it.